# & in function declaration return type

Tags: c++, function, return, memory-address

What does the & mean in the following?

```
class Something
{
 public:
   int m_nValue;

   const int& GetValue() const { return m_nValue; }
   int& GetValue() { return m_nValue; }
};
```

This code is taken from [here](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/810-const-class-objects-and-member-functions/).

Comment: Remember: references are syntatic sugar. Underneath it all, they are just pointers.

Comment: You probably should get a book on C++. It will answer this and lots of other basic questions.

Answer (score 5):

[It means return value by reference](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/returning_values_by_reference.htm):

```
   int& GetValue()
     ^ Means returns a reference of int
```

Like

```
int i = 10;

int& GetValue() {
    int &j = i;
    return j;
}
```

`j` is a reference of `i`, a global variable.

Note: In C++ you have three kinds of variables:

1. Value variable for example `int i = 10`.
2. Reference variable for example `int &j = i;`
   reference variable  creates alias of other variable, both are symbolic names of same memory location.
3. Address variable: `int* ptr = &i`. called pointers. Pointer variables use for holding address of a variable.

Deference in declaration

```
   Pointer:
           int  *ptr = &i;
                ^      ^  & is on the left side as an address operation
                |
                * For pointer variable.

   Reference:

           int &j = i;
               ^
               | & on the right side for reference
```

Remember in C you have only two kinds of variables value and address (pointer). Reference variables are in C++, and references are simple to use like value variables and as capable as pointer variables.

Pointers are like:

```
                      j = &i;

                      i                   j
                   +------+            +------+
                   | 10   |            | 200  |
                   +------+            +------+
                     202                 432
```

Reference are like:

```
                   int &j = i;

                    i, j
                   +------+
                   | 10   |
                   +------+
```

No memory is allocated for j. It's an alias of the same location in memory.

[*What are the differences between pointer variable and reference variable in C++?*](http://www.blogosfera.co.uk/2008/09/what-are-the-differences-between-pointer-variable-and-reference-variable-in-c/)

1. A pointer can be re-assigned any number of times while a reference can not be reassigned after initialization.
2. A pointer can point to NULL while a reference can never point to NULL
3. You can’t take the address of a reference like you can with pointers
4. There’s no “reference arithmetics” (but you can take the address of an object pointed by a reference and do pointer arithmetics on it as in &obj + 5).

<sub>Because as you commented, you have questions about the differences between pointers and reference variables, so I highly encourage you read the related pages from the link I have given in my answer.</sub>

Comment: @jazzybazz **NO** it means `j` is alias of `i`.

Comment: I believe your example results in undefined behaviour (at least if you try to use the returned value), since you're returning a reference to a local variable. From your link - `"When returning a reference, be careful that the object being referred to does not go out of scope."` Your example also doesn't really explain much.

Comment: @Dukeling you are **correct** because life of `i` is within function()