# How to make a type that is easily compared by reference

Tags: c++

How do you make a type that is compared by reference but enforce that it can't be created in functions (prevent references to stack/deleted objects).

I came up with the Error type below and was proud of it, until I realized you can do "return Error::New(...)" inside a function. The problem is in the h() function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Error {
    std::string _str;
    const Error &from;

    Error();
    Error(const char *s)
        : _str(s), from(*this)
    {
    }

public:
    Error(const Error &err)
        : from(err.from)
    {
    }

    static Error New(const char *s) {
        return Error(s);
    }

    bool operator== (const Error &rhs) const {
        return (&from == &rhs.from);
    }

    bool operator!= (const Error &rhs) const {
        return (&from != &rhs.from);
    }

    std::string ToString() {
        return from._str;
    }

public:
    static const Error None;
};

const Error Error::None("none");

// user errors
auto ErrConnect = Error::New("failed to connect");
auto ErrWrite = Error::New("invalid write");

Error f() {
    return ErrConnect;
}

Error g() {
    return Error::None;
}

Error h() {
    return Error::New("test");
}

int main()
{
    printf("ErrConnect == ErrConnect : %d\n", ErrConnect == ErrConnect);
    printf("ErrConnect == ErrWrite : %d\n", ErrConnect == ErrWrite);
    printf("f() == ErrConnect : %d\n", f() == ErrConnect);
    printf("f() == ErrWrite : %d\n", f() == ErrWrite);
    printf("f() != ErrConnect : %d\n", f() != ErrConnect);
    printf("f() != ErrWrite : %d\n", f() != ErrWrite);
    printf("f() == Error::None : %d\n", f() == Error::None);
    printf("f() != Error::None : %d\n", f() != Error::None);
    printf("g() == Error::None : %d\n", g() == Error::None);
    printf("g() != Error::None : %d\n", g() != Error::None);
    printf("f().ToString() : %s\n", f().ToString().c_str());
    printf("ErrConnect.ToString() : %s\n", ErrConnect.ToString().c_str());

    auto err = f();
    auto err2 = err;
    auto err3 = err2;
    printf("err3 == ErrConnect : %d\n", err3 == ErrConnect);

    auto err4 = h();
    printf("err4 from h() : %s\n", err4.ToString().c_str());
}
```

Comment: In reference variable  & only uses at time of declaration by using & in if you are comparing addresses of two. [difference between pointers and reference variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15995463/in-function-declaration-return-type/15995482#15995482)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found that the best way to implement this is using a static std::atomic counter (specifically, _uint_fast64_t seems best) from which ids are created for each error type in the Error(const char *s) constructor and std::atomic::fetch_add() to fetch/increment it:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic

The only drawback is that these are only present in C++11 (Visual Studio 2012; Linux should not be a problem except for old distros).

Answer (score 1):

Allowing something to be created at global scope, but not in a function, cannot be done.

Keeping track of the original `Error&` is not required for anything you are doing.  Instead, you want the creation of an error to create a unique token, and all `Error`s copied or moved from it to carry that token with them.  That token being `Error& this` is not required, but the lifetime of that token needs to extend over the lifetime of all `Error`s copied from the original.

One approach would be to use type tags, possibly macro assisted, to generate your errors.  With care, the token can be arranged to be both unique and not require extra work on a per-error basis.

As an example:

```
struct ErrorToken {
  virtual std::string Description() const = 0;
  ~ErrorToken() {}
};
template<typename T>
struct ErrorTokenImpl:ErrorToken {
  virtual std::string Description() const /* final override if C++11 */ {
    return T::desc();
  }
};
class Error {
  ErrorToken* token;
  template<typename T>
  static ErrorToken* get_token() {
    static std::unique_ptr<ErrorToken> retval( new ErrorTokenImpl<T>() );
    return retval.get();
  }
public:
  template<typename T>
  Error(): token( get_token<T>() );
  bool operator==(Error const& o) const { return token == o.token; } // etc
  std::string GetDescription() const {
    return token->Description();
  }
};

#define MAKE_ERROR(Y, X) Error< struct Y { static const char* desc() { return X; }; } >()
const Error ErrConnect = MAKE_ERROR(Connection, "failed to connect");
```

now, anyone can create an error in any context, but each creation of the error has a tag and a string, and the created `token` will last until static object cleanup time.

Comment: Thanks, it's an interesting idea but I wanted to get rid of the bookkeeping related to error types/error codes.

Comment: @ctn notice that if you create global `Error` values, each constructed with a different "type" and string, they'll be usable as just `return ErrorBlah;` -- you can create a local error code that isn't one of those with the `MAKE_ERROR` macro within a function (assuming sufficient C++11 support for local type template arguments), but unlike your original design it doesn't invoke undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using UUID's:

```
#include <boost/uuid/uuid.hpp>
#include <boost/uuid/uuid_generators.hpp>

using namespace std;

class Error {
    std::string msg;
    boost::uuids::uuid tag;

public:
    Error(const char *s)
        : msg(s), tag(boost::uuids::random_generator()())
    {
    }

    Error(const Error &rhs)
        : msg(rhs.msg), tag(rhs.tag)
    {
    }

    Error(Error &&rhs)
        : msg(std::move(rhs.msg)), tag(rhs.tag)
    {
    }

    Error &operator=(const Error &rhs) {
        msg = rhs.msg;
        tag = rhs.tag;
        return *this;
    }

    bool operator==(const Error &rhs) const {
        return (tag == rhs.tag);
    }

    bool operator!=(const Error &rhs) const {
        return (tag != rhs.tag);
    }

    std::string ToString() {
        return msg;
    }

public:
    static const Error None;
};

const Error Error::None("none");

// user errors
auto ErrConnect = Error("failed to connect");
auto ErrWrite = Error("invalid write");
```