# Subscripting a reference to const

Tags: c++, reference, constants

I'm here looking at some C++ code and am not understanding something. It is irrelevant but it comes from a YARP (robot middleware) tutorial which goes with the documentation.

```
virtual void getHeader(const Bytes& header) 
{
  const char *target = "HUMANITY";
  for (int i=0; i<8 && i<header.length(); i++) 
  {
    header.get()[i] = target[i]; 
  }
}
```

Now, header is a reference to const and thus cannot be modified within this function. `get` is called on it, its prototype is `char *get() const;`. How can `header.get()` be subscripted and modified ? The program compiles fine. I may have not understood what happens here but I'm basing myself on what I've read in C++ Primer...

I would very much appreciate a little clarification!

Have a nice day,

Comment: `char *get() const;` means pointer to char cannot be modified. pointee can be.

Comment: you're thinking of "char * const get()". The "const" on the right hand side of the function means "does not modify non-mutable members"

Answer (score 1):

```
char *get() const;
```

The right hand const means "this member doesn't alter anything in the class that's not mutable", and it's honoring that - it isn't changing anything. The implementation is probably something like this:

```
char *Bytes::get() const
{
    return const_cast<char *>(m_bytes);
}
```

The pointer that is being returned, however, is a simple "char*". Think of it this way:

```
(header.get())[i] = target[i];
// or
char* p = header.get();
p[i] = target[i];
```

Comment: Exactly, it returns a char * not a const char *.

Answer (score 0):

Whoever designed the interface decided that the content of a `const Byte` object can be modified by stuffing values into it. Presumably they've done whatever hacks they needed to make `header.get()[i]` modifiable. I wouldn't use this code as an exemplar of good interface design.

Comment: Alright, I figured out that it clearly wasn't optimal coding. I've digged a bit deeper and it turns out `get()` just returns an attribute called `data` which is `char*`. The `get()` function was indeed const but it returned something that wasn't.

Answer (score 0):

`header.get()` should returns `char*`, assuming it as base address and indexed with `[i]` and string in `target` coped to that location.

@antitrust given good point, return address can't be modified by address content can e.g.

```
char x[100];
char* get() const
{
   return x;
}
```

int calling function you can do like:

```
get()[i] = target[i];
```

it will copy `target` string to `x`, this method can be useful when `x` is *private member* to class, and you are to copy in `x`.

**Edit** if get() is [a inline function](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_inline_functions.htm)  then calling get() function in a loop will not effect performance., I mean such function should be defined inline.

Comment: But why does `const Bytes& header` not prohibit writing to internal data members of `header`?

Comment: @Vorac `const Bytes&` means reference to const, you can't change const. see here for [reference vs pointer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15995463/in-function-declaration-return-type/15995482#15995482) as return type

Comment: It is not defined inline. I'm starting to get all this, thanks to you all !

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [doc](http://wiki.icub.org/yarpdoc/classyarp_1_1os_1_1Bytes.html):

```
struct Bytes {
  char* get() const; // works
  char*& get() const; // would not work
  char* mem_;
};
```

This code is perfectly valid, even though it is bad practice. The
problem is that a copy of the pointer is made and the constness of the
class is `lost`. constness in C++ is largely conceptual and easy to
break (often even without consequences). I'd complain to the
implementer. It should look like this:

```
struct Bytes {
  char* get(); // works
  const char* get() const; // would not work
  char* mem_;
};
```