# int &a = b makes 'a' a pointer to 'b' in C 4.8.1 but not in C, Why? (Call By Reference)

Tags: c++, c, variables, pointers

[The code in C++](http://ideone.com/OdBSna) - Ideone

```
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

void swap(int &a, int &b){
    printf("%d %d\n", a, b);
        printf("%d %d\n", &a, &b);

    int temp=a;
    a=b;
    b=temp;
}

int main(void) {
    int a=2, b=5;
    printf("%d %d\n", a, b);
            printf("%d %d\n", &a, &b);

    swap(a,b);
    printf("%d %d\n", a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT-

2 5

-1076828408 -1076828404

2 5

-1076828408 -1076828404

5 2

[The code in C](http://ideone.com/lqtyUY) - Ideone

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap(int &a, int &b){
    printf("%d %d\n", a, b);
        printf("%d %d\n", &a, &b);

    int temp=a;
    a=b;
    b=temp;
}

int main(void) {
    int a=2, b=5;
    printf("%d %d\n", a, b);
            printf("%d %d\n", &a, &b);

    swap(a,b);
    printf("%d %d\n", a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

compilation info

prog.c:3:15: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘&’ token

```
void swap(int &a, int &b){
              ^
```

prog.c: In function ‘main’:

prog.c:15:4: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]

```
printf("%d %d\n", &a, &b);
^
```

prog.c:15:4: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]

prog.c:17:2: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘swap’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  swap(a,b);
  ^

**why does it work in C++ as call be reference, but not in C?**

**What does int &a; mean?**

Comment: It's a reference, not a pointer. `C` doesn't have references. I'd suggest buying a book on C++.

Comment: C doesn't have references.

Comment: Read [& in function declaration return type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15995463/in-function-declaration-return-type/15995482#15995482)

Comment: Because you confuse C++/C read [Assigning int value to an address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17852911/assigning-int-value-to-an-address/17852936#17852936)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

& used in function definitions like that are called references. They're different from pointers and are not supported in C.

Comment: got it, Thanks for the info. and now I remember studying this a while back.. I stumbled upon it while studying pointers in C and it didn't look like call by value, nor the call by reference we study generally.